# Can't get my flask python app to work on Heroku - application error

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I have tried to follow all advice on SO but no luck so far.

My procfile is set  as: `web: gunicorn main:app` and the  main.py is within the root folder. Within it  are also two other .py files that the main.py file imports functions from.

Requirements.txt includes all modules and libraries (including Sumy, even though it  says otherwise in  the logs below).

Here are the error logs:

```
Adams-MacBook-Pro:apptest adamk.hacklander$ heroku logs --tail
2020-05-28T16:08:22.591466+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-28 16:08:22 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-05-28T16:08:22.596477+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-28 16:08:22 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-05-28T16:08:22.678863+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-28 16:08:22 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076803+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-28 16:08:23 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076836+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076838+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076845+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076846+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076846+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076847+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076847+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076847+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076848+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076848+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076848+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076848+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076849+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076849+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076850+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076850+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076851+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076851+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076852+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076852+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076853+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076853+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076853+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076854+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/main.py", line 3, in <module>
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076854+00:00 app[web.1]: from sumy.nlp.tokenizers import Tokenizer
2020-05-28T16:08:23.076854+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sumy'
2020-05-28T16:08:23.077080+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-28 16:08:23 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078331+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-28 16:08:23 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078332+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078332+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078332+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078332+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078333+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078333+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078333+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078333+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078333+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078334+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078334+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078334+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078334+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078335+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078335+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078335+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078335+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078336+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078336+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078337+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078337+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078337+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078337+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078338+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/main.py", line 3, in <module>
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078338+00:00 app[web.1]: from sumy.nlp.tokenizers import Tokenizer
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078338+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sumy'
2020-05-28T16:08:23.078588+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-28 16:08:23 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2020-05-28T16:08:23.124574+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-05-28T16:08:23.124591+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in run
2020-05-28T16:08:23.124881+00:00 app[web.1]: self.sleep()
2020-05-28T16:08:23.124899+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 357, in sleep
2020-05-28T16:08:23.125155+00:00 app[web.1]: ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
2020-05-28T16:08:23.125157+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2020-05-28T16:08:23.125312+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2020-05-28T16:08:23.125333+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2020-05-28T16:08:23.125553+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2020-05-28T16:08:23.125622+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2020-05-28T16:08:23.125625+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-28T16:08:23.125625+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2020-05-28T16:08:23.125626+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-28T16:08:23.125659+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-05-28T16:08:23.125659+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
2020-05-28T16:08:23.125747+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
2020-05-28T16:08:23.125764+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in run
2020-05-28T16:08:23.125870+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2020-05-28T16:08:23.125887+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 228, in run
2020-05-28T16:08:23.126050+00:00 app[web.1]: super().run()
2020-05-28T16:08:23.126052+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2020-05-28T16:08:23.126165+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
2020-05-28T16:08:23.126182+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
2020-05-28T16:08:23.126325+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2020-05-28T16:08:23.126341+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
2020-05-28T16:08:23.126520+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
2020-05-28T16:08:23.126536+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 382, in stop
2020-05-28T16:08:23.126719+00:00 app[web.1]: sock.close_sockets(self.LISTENERS, unlink)
2020-05-28T16:08:23.126736+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 209, in close_sockets
2020-05-28T16:08:23.126872+00:00 app[web.1]: sock_name = sock.getsockname()
2020-05-28T16:08:23.126896+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 36, in __getattr__
2020-05-28T16:08:23.126983+00:00 app[web.1]: def __getattr__(self, name):
2020-05-28T16:08:23.126998+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2020-05-28T16:08:23.127140+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2020-05-28T16:08:23.127157+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2020-05-28T16:08:23.127369+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2020-05-28T16:08:23.127405+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2020-05-28T16:08:23.190477+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-05-28T16:08:23.228743+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-28T16:23:11.720745+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=summarizernews-app.herokuapp.com request_id=c8934b59-1775-4092-95e3-dabdb644d052 fwd="88.211.106.62" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-28T16:23:12.371335+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=summarizernews-app.herokuapp.com request_id=afbb685c-bf29-4951-bf90-f865d6b1af92 fwd="88.211.106.62" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I appreciate  any help

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but have you committed the change to `requirements.txt` which adds `sumy`? And what version of `sumy` are you asking Heroku to load?

Comment: So I just ran ```cat requirements.txt``` in Heroku bash and apparently, Sumy is not loaded in there :/. I am asking it to load sumy==0.8.1. Any idea why is that? I have committed the change multiple times via ```git add . > git commit -m " " > git push heroku master```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure what's going on there.

Comment: Could you double check your local requirements.txt file to confirm that  sumy==0.8.1, exist in there. Your git process seems to be on track. That's the only thing I can think of. If you do have it there and it still does not work something else you can try is deleting the requirements.txt file from heroku. Deleting requirements.txt file from local. Comitting the fact that you have deleted the local req.txt file. Regenerating the requirements.txt file. Adding that back to your git tracked files. and redeploying to heroku @AdamKristofHackländer. Owh, and also delete all your __pycache__ files

Comment: Basically the steps above is what generally known in the IT world as "Have you tried turning it on and off again?" :D